# Monodroid Animation values

Tags: android, xamarin.android

What are the equivalents of these Android features in Monodroid? Can't find them!

```
Animation.ABSOLUTE 
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF 
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT
```

The Monodroid documentation is just ridiculos..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to find these is to search in View->Object Browser:

Android.Views.Animations.Dimension